# Prove that $1, 1+x, (1+x)^2,\ldots$, forms a basis for $\Bbb R[X]$ as a $\Bbb R$ vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we prove that the polynomials $1, 1+X, (1+X)^2, (1+X)^3 ...$ form a basis for $\Bbb R[x]$, where $\Bbb R(x)$ is the polynomial ring(which is also a vector space over $\Bbb R$)?

I think we have to use the binomial expansion of $(1+X)^n$, but I don't know how.

Comment: Do you already know a basis for the polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

Show that the map 
$$f(a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n)=a_0+a_1(1+X)+\cdots+a_n(1+X)^n$$
is a one-to-one and onto linear transformation.

Since $\{1, X, X^2,\ldots X^n\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R[X]$, $\{1,1+X,(1+X)^2,\ldots\}$ will be also.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that

> For every $n\in\mathbb N$, $\quad1,x,\dots,x^n$ and $1,1+x,\dots,(1+x)^n$ generate the same subspace.

Use the binomial theorem on $(1+x)^n$ to get $x^n$.